# Find first empty cell in Col U & copy/paste adjacent value from Col O

Tags: vba, excel

I've been struggling with what I thought would be a very easy/simple piece of code.

I would like to create a loop to find the first empty cell in Col U & copy the adjacent value in Col O (number representing month) to the empty cell in Col U, but convert the number to month name.

I want this loop to run in the worksheet "Adjustments" only, automatically transposing the month name to Col U (from # in Col O) as new entries are made.

So far I've managed this:

```
Sub MonthName()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Adjustments")
    For Each cell In ws.Columns(21).Cells
         If Len(cell) = 0 Then cell.Offset(0, -6).Copy: Exit For
    Next cell
End Sub
```

[image]

Really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest you use `Find` to get the first blank cell rather than loop.

If you want this to run automatically you could trigger it from a sheet change event (when a particular range of cells is updated, or selected, or calculated etc).

```
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim rng1 As Range

 Set ws = Sheets("Adjustments") 
 Set rng1 = ws.Columns("U").Find("", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "U"), xlFormulas, xlWhole)
 If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then rng1.Value = Format(ws.Cells(rng1.Row, "O") + 1, "mmm")
```

*updated*

- right click your sheet called *adjustments*
- *View Code*
- copy and paste in the code below

*code*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range

Set rng1 = Intersect(Columns("O"), Target)
If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Set rng1 = Columns("U").Find("", Cells(Rows.Count, "U"), xlFormulas, xlWhole)
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    rng1.Value = Format(Cells(rng1.Row, "O") + 1, "mmm")
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @brettdj - that worked perfectly!

It would be great if it could run following a trigger - perhaps when month# are added in Col O?

Comment: Also, can the code be edited so that once the month name is transposed it's pasted as a value, so won't change if the month # is deleted/change? Thanks @brettdj

Comment: Thank you @brettdj! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

```
If Len(Trim(cell.Value)) = 0 Then cell.Value = MonthName(cell.Offset(, -6).Value)
```

And remove that `Exit For` IF you want to change all empty cells at columns `U` not only the first one. Otherwise keep it.